# New to DOJO dojo not loading

Tags: dojo

I am new to dojo. I have tried to set up a sample Dojo page, but Dojo components are not loading. Instead I get the following error

> ReferenceError: dojo is not defined
> dojo.require("dijit.form.Dialog");

But the CSS is applied, class="dijitHidden" hides the DIV.

Below is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css">
<script language="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" ></script>
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        isDebug: true,
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true
        //foo: "bar"
    };
</script>
<script>
    dojo.require("dojo.Dialog");
    function showDialog(){
        dijit.byId("terms").show();
    }
    function hideDialog(){
    dijit.byId("terms").hide();
    }
</script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title> Hello Dojo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to Dojo</h1>
<div id="contentDiv">
    <button onclick="showDialog()" > view terms and conditions</button>
    <div class="dijitHidden">
        <div data-dojo-type="digit.Dialog" style="widht:600px" data-dojo-props="title:'terms and conditions'" id="terms">
            Digit Dialog Box Appears
            <button onclick="hideDialog();"> I Agree</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS and JavaScript are separate. Just because the CSS loads correctly and classes control the display of elements that doesn't mean the JavaScript has loaded at all. I would guess that the path to the dojo.js file is incorrect, and that it's not in a directory called dojo located in the same directory as your HTML page.

Comment: does dojo get defined when using `async: true`? I thought you only got `require` and you had to pull in anything else you needed through that...

Comment: I don't know if this matters or not, but I include dojo.js after the dojo config

Comment: hi Antony, yes you are right. I used web Console in FF and i can see that the dojo.js is loading properly.

Hi David, i intend to use more things.... but stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Also already answered in the comments, dojoConfig is defined too late.  Also, you need to use require:

`require(["dijit/form/Dialog"], function (formDialog) {...});`

Comment: Well that if he is using AMD. Depends what version of Dojo

Comment: otherwise dojo would exist (he confirmed dojo.js loads)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Dojo 1.6 or some version without AMD support.
The code looks fine,maybe you need to change language="text/javascript" to type="text/javascript" or  you can debug on the very next line with:

```
console.log(dojo);
alert("Wait");
```

and check if dojo is getting loaded properly.

I would also  suggest to check with CDN dojo library version if nothing works for now.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

dojoConfig must come before rendering of dojo.js file.

Your coding style is showing dojo <1.7. So, use djConfig instead of dojoConfig.

Your got mistake at data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog"